# How do I tell Ghostscript not to use the clipping path in a conversion from eps to tiff?

Tags: windows, command-line, ghostscript

I want to convert an image with ghostscript from eps to tiff via windows commandline. It works fine, except Ghosscript applies the clipping path to the image, cutting away the background. How do I tell Ghostscript not to apply it, but leave the path in the image?

current used parameters are:

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK -sDEVICE=tiff32nc -r300x300 -dEPSCrop -sCompression=none -transparency -sOutputFile="output.tif" "source.eps" -c quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can't, because the clip path is part of the PostScript program.

Your only option is to edit the PostScript program and remove the clip path. Unless, of course, I'm missing your point, but without an example to look at its not entirely clear what you are asking.

Be careful about using the term 'image' here, that has a specific meaning in PostScript, and I am not certain that you are using it in a way consistent with that meaning. While an EPS **may** contain an image, it need not.

Note that much of your command line does not make sense:

You are using -sColorConversionStrategy which is a control specific to the pdfwrite device, though you are using the tiff32nc device.

You have also specified -transparency, which is invalid, since it does not being with -s or -d and is in any event not a switch understood by Ghopstscript. For me this gives a warning about ignoring an unknown switch.

Of course, since you have also specified -dQUIET useful messages like this will be suppressed.....

Finally the -c quit doesn't do anything useful when you have already specified -dBATCH

Comment: Is "picture" a better term? I meant the embedded or in the process of conversion rasterized bitmap. In any case: Thanks for your hints.

Comment: Well, I normally use 'content', but picture seems reasonable. I'm still not sure I properly understand the problem, can you post an example file somewhere ?